# scaffold-dbcontext in multi sub-project .netcore 3.1 project fails

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.1

I am sure this has to be a naive question but I have a C#, .Netcore 3.1 project that has two sub projects.  Both sub projects are MVC applications although one is named "APP" and the other "API".

This project exists in .Netcore 2.2 and generally works.  There was a particular issue and I wondered if trying the latest version would fix it so I created the new 3.1 version, moved files...

Ok, in the 2.2 version I have `Models` folders in each sub project.  Each has exactly the same models.  I used the `Scaffold-DbContext` package manager command to build them.  It would make sense to be able to factor the shared models out but I didn't/don't know how to do that.

In the 3.1 version, I visit the first subproject (API) and do the scaffolding and it works.  I then try to do the same thing in the APP version and get the message:

```
PM> Scaffold-DbContext -Connection "Server=db.my.company.com;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True" -Context MyDbContext -Schemas "MySchema" -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models\MySchema -Force
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Could not load assembly 'API'. Ensure it is referenced by the startup project 'APP'.
```

This is not what I expected.  It seems like something from within the API subproject is leaking out into the APP subproject.  I expected the scaffolding to just build the models from the remote DB and stick the resulting files in the currently active project's Models folder.

I have used `WinGrep` to search for `API` in the `APP` section and see nothing.

If the answer is to factor out the duplicated models and let both sub-projects use them please let me know how that is done and/or point me at the correct docs.

Answer (score 0):

So I don't have a complete answer but I have an answer.  Likely the initial scaffolding set something in the global project config and that is conflicting with trying to do the same operation again in another subproject.

This become more of a project architecture question than anything i think.  I can think of two ways to solve this and I bet there are others.

1. Create yet another sub-project and let that hold the models that are common between the API and APP projects.  The APP and API projects then link the new project as a dependency.  I didn't know that you could do that.
2. What i chose to do was just use the models in the API project and just have the APP project set the API as a dependency.

There may be even better ways but this is what i have at the moment.